# page redirecting to itself

Tags: php, zend-framework, redirect

```
<a href="<?php $this->url(array('controller' => 'page', 'action' => 'page-detail', 'page_id' => $show_today['id']));?>"><?php echo $show_today['id']; ?></a>
```

Am i syntactically wrong in the above statement. Because the link does not take me anywhere but the same page I am in.

the controller,action and the values are all correct. But the link does not go to the respective page.

Comment: What is the outcome when you click?

Comment: it goes to the same page..i.e sort of refreshing the same page..

Comment: It seems `url> 'page'` doesn't have any outcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe an echo is missing?

```
//             here
<a href="<?php echo $this->url(array('controller' => 'page', 'action' => 'page-detail', 'page_id' => $show_today['id']));?>"><?php echo $show_today['id']; ?></a>
```